# Signature without equality

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is it possible to construct in the signature without equality the formula, which has 2-elements model and hasn't 3-elements model?

I think no, but have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that for any formulas without equality the following holds.

1. Any consistent set of formulas has a countable model.
2. If a formula has some model, it has a model of any higher cardinality.

So, if your formula without equality has any model whatsoever, it has a countable model.

Comment: So, there are some easy example of such formula?

Comment: Of which formula?

Comment: Actually, I didn't quite understand, how my statement follows from your answer

Comment: Thanks. I added a missing clause. You need a part of Loewenhem-Skolem theorem (3.).

Comment: Can you explain, how to prove the 3th statement in this case? Or can we solve this problem without this theorem?

Comment: You simply need to redefine an interpretation of your symbols in such a way that they will work on a larger model.